# Copy a row in excel if it matches a specific criteria into a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a novice to VBA and having issues in copying rows in one sheet to another based on certain criteria.

I have tried searching for an answer in this forum, tried modifying the code to suit my requirement but been unsuccessful. Please help me.

1. I need to search for no.s in column A of a worksheet. The search should start with No. 1, then 2, then 3 and so on.
2. Whenever "1" is found, copy the entire row to "Sheet 1".
3. After completing search for "1", start for "2". When a match is found, copy entire row to "Sheet 2".
4. Similarly No. "3" and so on.
5. Repeat this search for other no.s till end of column A.

I have tried the following code:
Note: i will vary from 1 to a pre-determined value.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim lRow As Long '<~~ Not Integer. Might give you error in higher versions of excel
Dim strSearch As Integer

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Burn Down")
strSearch = "1"

With ws1

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    '~~> I am assuming that the names are in Col A
    '~~> if not then change A below to whatever column letter
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("A3:A" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
        Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

'~~> Destination File
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\CSVimport\Sample.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet" & i)

With ws2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A3"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lRow = 1
    End If

    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End With

wb2.Save
wb2.Close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative way of doing it. I don't like using filters, I prefer to loop through each record. Maybe it's a litte slower but I think it's more robust.

- The below should work but I didn't understand if you wanted to paste the row into a new worksheet in the current workbook or a new workbook.
- The below code pastes into the current workbook but that can easily be changed.
- I'm also assuming you will want to keep pasting new rows into the worksheet so therefore you don't want to overwrite any previous data you have written.
- You would also want to put in some extra error checking like ensure the worksheet\workbook exits, ensure the value in Column A is numeric etc. The below has none.

  ```
  Sub copyBurnDownItem()


  Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
  Dim rngBurnDown As Range
  Dim rngCell As Range
  Dim strPasteToSheet As String

  'Used for the new worksheet we are pasting into
  Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
  Dim rngNextAvailbleRow As Range

  'Define the worksheet with our data
  Set objWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Burn Down")


  'Dynamically define the range to the last cell.
  'This doesn't include and error handling e.g. null cells
  'If we are not starting in A1, then change as appropriate
  Set rngBurnDown = objWorksheet.Range("A1:A" & objWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count,     "A").End(xlUp).Row)

  'Now loop through all the cells in the range
  For Each rngCell In rngBurnDown.Cells

  objWorksheet.Select

  If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
      'select the entire row
      rngCell.EntireRow.Select

      'copy the selection
      Selection.Copy

      'Now identify and select the new sheet to paste into
      Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & rngCell.Value)
      objNewSheet.Select

      'Looking at your initial question, I believe you are trying to find the next     available row
      Set rngNextAvailbleRow = objNewSheet.Range("A1:A" &     objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)


      Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
  End If

  Next rngCell

  objWorksheet.Select
  objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

  'Can do some basic error handing here

  'kill all objects
  If IsObject(objWorksheet) Then Set objWorksheet = Nothing
  If IsObject(rngBurnDown) Then Set rngBurnDown = Nothing
  If IsObject(rngCell) Then Set rngCell = Nothing
  If IsObject(objNewSheet) Then Set objNewSheet = Nothing
  If IsObject(rngNextAvailbleRow) Then Set rngNextAvailbleRow = Nothing

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: I tried to use your code but it is giving "subscript out of range error - 9"...I don't know how to debug this..please help...

Comment: sounds like something is missing. Do you have a sheet called 'Burn Down' which contains all your values? (i.e. No 1,2,3 etc).
The code begins in cell A1 on the burn down sheet. Is this your starting position or is it A2, A3....?
When you get the error, you can click debug. The code will be highlighted on the line where it errors. You could paste that line here fore further help.

Comment: I am getting the error at "Set objWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Burn Down")". I do have a sheet called "Burn Down" with values in column A -- 1,2,3 and so on. Sorry it starts from A3, but i modified your code to start from A3. I do not know why I am getting this error at this line. And also the contents in column A are just numbers, i mean it has only 1 or 2 0r 3 and so on.

Comment: you could try removing the ThisWorkbook reference? So instead the line will read: Set objWorksheet = Worksheets("Burn Down"). Or: Set objWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Burn Down")

Comment: I tried ActiveWorkbook.Sheets instead. It worked for me. Can you please tell me what does this line of code means : "If rngCell.Value <> "" Then " ?? Now the code is stopping at "Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & rngCell.Value)". Here, I again used ActiveWorkbook.Sheets but still not working...please help me

Comment: I was able to solve this error. Now the code is stopping at Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select...I am still debugging it

Comment: I solved almost all issues with the code you gave me. But only last glitch : As I said in my previous comment the code was stopping at "Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select". So, I changed it to objWorksheet.Range. The code ran successfully but the first row is getting overwritten so I have only one entry in each sheet. In your code it is being checked for available next row, but even then it is overwritten.

Comment: objWorksheet refers to the 'Burn Down' sheet so that won't work. Try objNewSheet.Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select  objNewSheet refers to the new sheet you are going to paste into (sheet1 or sheet2 etc). This is the line which should check for the next available row. For your other question "If rngCell.Value <> "" Then... This is just a conditional statement which checks that there is always a value in column A. If for example one of the cells half way down was blank, the code could error. So this checks for empty cells and if empty it skips over them. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It will go through a list of entries like "No. 1", "No. 2", ... in column A.

It starts with checking sheets availability and then copy each row to the appropriate sheet. You might need to adjust to your particular scenario but it should work.

```
Sub CopyRowsToSheets()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = wbk.Sheets("Burn Down")

    Dim shtTarget As Worksheet

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iRow As Integer

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iMax As Integer

    'get max value
    Set rng = sht.Range("A1")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        i = CInt(Mid(rng.Value, 4))
        If i > iMax Then iMax = i
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend
    'MsgBox iMax

    'check sheets availability
    For i = 1 To iMax
        If wbk.Sheets("Sheet" & i) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sheet" & i & " is missing"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    'copy to other sheets
    Set rng = sht.Range("A1")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        i = CInt(Mid(rng.Value, 4))
        rng.EntireRow.Copy

        Set shtTarget = wbk.Sheets("Sheet" & i)
        shtTarget.Activate
        iRow = shtTarget.Range("A" & shtTarget.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        shtTarget.Range("A" & iRow).Select
        DoEvents
        shtTarget.Paste
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: This code seems to be not working for me...My excel is not responding...i mean it is going to an infinite loop... I have to kill excel to resume...not able to find the error

Comment: I tried debugging your code, and I found that the control is not coming out of While loop. I do not know the reason though. Also, the string to be searched in column A is "1", "2", "3" and so on. I thin you got confused by my problem statement, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

@Eddie the code finally worked. This is how it looks:

```
Sub Copy()

Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rngBurnDown As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim strPasteToSheet As String

'Used for the new worksheet we are pasting into
Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim rngNextAvailbleRow As Range

'Define the worksheet with our data
Set objWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Burn Down")

'Dynamically define the range to the last cell.
'This doesn't include and error handling e.g. null cells
'If we are not starting in A1, then change as appropriate
Set rngBurnDown = objWorksheet.Range("A3:A" & objWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

'Now loop through all the cells in the range
For Each rngCell In rngBurnDown.Cells

objWorksheet.Select

If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
    'select the entire row
    rngCell.EntireRow.Select

    'copy the selection
    Selection.Copy

    'Now identify and select the new sheet to paste into
    Set objNewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Burn Down " & rngCell.Value)
    objNewSheet.Select

    'Looking at your initial question, I believe you are trying to find the next     available row
    Set rngNextAvailbleRow = objNewSheet.Range("A1:A" & objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
'MsgBox "Success"
    objNewSheet.Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

Next rngCell

objWorksheet.Select
objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```